# Python Django script throwing an error -HTTPConnectionPool Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apache, httpresponse

I have Django App and I am trying to get data from our server. The code is as below:

```
def login(request):
   #global userlist, login_data
    if request.method == "POST":
            # get email or mobile_number and password from login.html screen
        email_id = request.POST.get("your_name")
        password = request.POST.get("your_pass")
        
        try:

            login_data = requests.get('http://<our URL>/api/usersapi/?mobile_number=' + email_id + '&password=' + password,  timeout=0.05).json()  # get user api json data
               
            if len(login_data) == 1:  # check dictionary of login_data is empty or not
                for x in login_data:
                    user_type = x['user_type']
                    user_id = x['user_id']
                    request.session['login_data'] = user_id
                    request.session["admin_status"] = True
                return render(request, 'gui/dashboard.html', {'user_type': user_type, 'login_data': login_data})
            else:  # if correct details then return to dashboard page
                return render(request, 'gui/login.html', {'msg': 'Wrong Username and Password'})
            
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            print(e)
            r = "No response"
            return render(request, 'gui/login.html', {'msg': e})
            
    return render(request, 'gui/login.html')
```

It throws an error while establishing the connection.

HTTPConnectionPool Max retries exceeded with  (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3b389becc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',

I have already seen and applied many solutions related to the same error. But, I am not able to figure out the problem. Our system ulimit-> 65536

I have configured settings using WSGI. and /etc/hosts has our url entry

Any help or guidence is appreciated.

Regards,
PD